# Input to python function using bash script

Tags: argparse

I have a function which takes its inputs in the following form from a .sh file

`my_fun.py --arg1 $arg1 --arg2 $arg2 --arg3 $arg3`

The question here is that based on the value of arg1, the number of inputs is different. How can I implement it using `argparse`?

Here I want to use `parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()`, but I do not know how many lines to read.

Thanks.

I do not have much idea.

Comment: `argparse` is best when you, the programmer, specifies which flags (e.g. `--foobar`), it will accept.  The parsing, the help display, and error checking all depend on that.  For a free form input you might as well work with `sys.argv` directly.

Comment: Would you please explain the *the number of inputs is different* part?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a suggestion: Parse your arguments in 2 passes. In the first pass, you parse `--arg1`. Then base on the the value you got, build a parser to parse the rest.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import argparse

# First pass: parse only --arg1
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("--arg1")
options, remainder = parser.parse_known_args()

# Second pass: parse the rest.
# Say if --arg1 is foo, we got 2 additional flags,
# if --arg1 is bar, we got 1 more
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
if options.arg1 == "foo":
    parser.add_argument("--arg2")
    parser.add_argument("--arg3")
elif options.arg1 == "bar":
    parser.add_argument("--arg4")
parser.parse_args(remainder, options)
print(options)
```

Here are some interactions:

```bash
$ python3 main.py --arg1 foo --arg2 cow --arg3 dog
Namespace(arg1='foo', arg2='cow', arg3='dog')

$ python3 main.py --arg1 bar --arg4 cat
Namespace(arg1='bar', arg4='cat')
```

#### Notes

- In the first pass, we use `parse_known_arg` to parse only `--arg1` and ignore the rest. The result is stored into a namespace object, `options`. The rest of the command line is stored in `remainder`.
- In the second pass, we build a new parser and based on the value of `--arg1` to add different arguments.
- Also in the second pass, when we call `parse_args`, we pass in the namespace from previous call, `options`. This way, we consolidate all command line flags into a single namespace object.